# Python Flask-sqlAlchemy Prepapre query

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working on an API made with python flask-SQLalchemy.

I'm looking for an elegant way prepare my query step by step.

Today my code is working but seam very hugly to me because of many duplicated content :

```
   if filteron is None:
    if orderby == 'config':
        if order == 'DESC':
            job = JobFull.query.order_by(JobFull.config_id.desc()).limit(limit).all()
        else:
            job = JobFull.query.order_by(JobFull.config_id.asc()).limit(limit).all()

    elif orderby == 'crawler':
        if order == 'DESC':
            job = JobFull.query.order_by(JobFull.crawler_id.desc()).limit(limit).all()
        else:
            job = JobFull.query.order_by(JobFull.crawler_id.asc()).limit(limit).all()

    elif orderby == 'site':
        if order == 'DESC':
            job = JobFull.query.order_by(JobFull.site_id.desc()).limit(limit).all()
        else:
            job = JobFull.query.order_by(JobFull.site_id.asc()).limit(limit).all()

    else:
        if order == 'DESC':
            job = JobFull.query.order_by(JobFull.job_id.desc()).limit(limit).all()
        else:
            job = JobFull.query.order_by(JobFull.job_id.asc()).limit(limit).all()
```

what i would like to do is prepare my query like :

```
if filteron is None:
    if order == 'DESC':
        job = job.query.orderby.desc()
    if orderby == 'config':
        job = job.query.orderby.(JobFull.config_id)
    if limit is not None:
        job = job.limit(limit)
```

is there an elegant way to do that or does I need to continue in my **if nightmare** ?

regards,

Answer (score 2):

Extrapolate your logic into a reusable function, combined with the `getattr` function.

```
def create_query(model, orderby: str='', desc: bool=False, limit: int=0):
    """ model: your SQLAlchemy Model
        orderby: the name of the column you want to order by
        desc: switch to order by Descending
        limit: limit the number of results returned"""

    query = model.query
    if orderby:
        col = getattr(model, orderby)
        col = col.desc() if desc else col.asc()
        query = query.order_by(col)

    if limit:
        query = query.limit(limit)

    return query.all()
```

Comment: Hi,
sorry for delay...
thanks for this proposal who look very sexy to me !
i'll try it asap and feedback